# javascript changing attributes works on first click only

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to move through each question of a form using jquery to hide/show other parts of the form. The first next click function works to change the id but the second won't register. I know I must be missing something obvious. Thanks.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $("#prev").hide()
        $("#item-vfb-42").hide()
        $("#item-vfb-43").hide()
        $("#item-vfb-31").hide()
        $("#item-vfb-44").hide()
        $("#item-vfb-45").hide()
        $("#item-vfb-46").hide()
        $("#item-vfb-47").hide()
    $("#next").click(function () {
        $("#next" ).prop( "id", "next1" );
        $("#prev").show()
        $("#item-vfb-30").hide()  
        $("#item-vfb-42").show()
    }); 
    $("#next1").click(function () {
        $("#next1" ).prop( "id", "next2" ); 
        $("#item-vfb-42").hide()
       $("#item-vfb-43").show()
    });
    $("#next2").click(function () {
        $("#next2" ).attr( "id", "next3" ); 
        $("#item-vfb-43").hide()
       $("#item-vfb-31").show()
    });
    $("#next3").click(function () {
        $("#next3" ).attr( "id", "next4" ); 
        $("#item-vfb-31").hide()
       $("#item-vfb-44").show()
    });
    $("#next4").click(function () {
        $("#next4" ).attr( "id", "next5" ); 
        $("#item-vfb-44").hide()
       $("#item-vfb-45").show()
    });
    $("#next5").click(function () {
        $("#next5" ).attr( "id", "next6" ); 
        $("#item-vfb-45").hide()
       $("#item-vfb-46").show()
    });
    $("#next6").click(function () {
        $("#prev6").hide()
        $("#next6" ).attr( "id", "next7" ); 
        $("#item-vfb-46").hide()
       $("#item-vfb-47").show()
    });
    $("#prev").click(function () {
        $("#next1" ).attr( "id", "next" );
        $("#prev").hide()
        $("#item-vfb-30").show()
        $("#item-vfb-42").hide() 
    });             
});
```

Comment: Why so many of your calls don't end with a semicolon?

Comment: Changing ID doesn't changes its event

Comment: You are changing the id dynamically and binding click event to the ids that never existed at the time of binding. You can instead bind it to a class and change your approach rather than adding so many event handlers. As a quick fix using an event delegation while binding the event will work

Answer (score 0):

You should change for exemple:

```
$("#next6").click(function () {
//some code
});
```

to

```
$("#next6").on("click",(function () {
//some code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that all of your click functions are being registered when the page loads. At the time of page load, only `#next` exists, so none of your other functions will work. I would fix this by using a `data-` attribute, and checking this when the button is clicked.

Let's say your button looks like this:

`<button id="#next" data-step="0">Next</button>`

Then you could do something like this:

```
$('#next').click( function( ) {
    var step = $(this).attr('data-step');

    if( step == 0 )
    {
        //do stuff for inital click
        $(this).attr('data-step', 1); //set attribute to next step
    }

    if( step == 1 )
    {
      //do stuff for next step...
      //etc etc...
    }
});
```

Comment: okay, I will give this a try. I know my first approach was not the best. I'm a beginner at this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you try to attack a click binding to `$('#next1')` is doesn't exist yet.

You could try doing it like this:

```
$("#next").click(function(){
    $("#next").prop( "id", "next1" );
    $("#prev").show();
    $("#item-vfb-30").hide() ; 
    $("#item-vfb-42").show();
    $("#next1").click(function(){
        // continue nesting your click bindings so they don't get called until the element exists.
    });
});
```

Comment: So essentially .click can only register once on any given element.

Comment: Not quite. It's just that when you call $("#next1") there isn't an element on the page with the ID of "next1" because the user hasn't clicked the next button yet. So jquery says"okay lets attach this function to '#next1.'" "Oh there is no '#next1' so let's not do anything."

Comment: The thing that might be confusing you is that you are writing ```$('#next1',function()...``` after you write ```$("#next").prop( "id", "next1" );``` but that isn't the order that they get executed in since the ID change doesn't occur until after click. My way allows you to not do the binding until after the click has occurred.

Comment: Okay, your explanation helps but the nesting didn't work. But the above with steps did work. I do understand now why my original code was not working.